# Where are default fields in BuildConfig generated by gradle defined?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, default-value, buildconfig

By default my gradle (via Android Studio) generates `BuildConfig` with some fields inside:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.my.package";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 14101415;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";
}
```

**Where are those fields defined to be generated?**

Answer (score 0):

They are generated by the compiler using the `gradle.conf` file

Comment: Do you know where can I find this file?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ?